# How to change the shape, colour and contour of an arrow in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to put a series of arrows on top of a dot plot. After hacking ggplot a bit, I got to put the arrows in place:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
N_seq <- rep(seq(1,50,by=1),2)
Y_seq <- rnorm(100)
Speci <- c(rep("Sample1",50),rep("Sample2",50))
Arrow_tail_x <- c(rep(0,20),rep(20,20),rep(30,10))
Arrow_head_x <- c(rep(20,20),rep(30,20),rep(50,10))
Arrow_tail_y <- c(rep(max(Y_seq)*0.25 + max(Y_seq),50))
Arrow_head_y <- c(rep(max(Y_seq)*0.25 + max(Y_seq),50))

data <- data.frame(N_seq,Y_seq,Speci,Arrow_tail_x,Arrow_tail_y,Arrow_head_x,Arrow_head_y)

p <- ggplot(data=data,aes(x=N_seq,y=Y_seq)) +
  theme_bw() + theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor= element_blank(),axis.line=element_line(colour="black")) +
  ylim(min(Y_seq),max(Y_seq)*0.25 + max(Y_seq)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0,10,20,30,40,50),labels=c(0,100,200,300,400,500)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=Arrow_tail_x,xend=Arrow_head_x,y=Arrow_head_y , yend=Arrow_tail_y),arrow = arrow(length=unit(20,"mm"),type='closed')) +
  geom_point(aes(color=Speci))

png("segment.png")
p
dev.off()
```

However, this code produces the standard black arrow with very narrow stalk. So far I have been unable to find how to change the arrows beyond using a different colour. How can I produce more stylish arrows? Does R has only one type of arrow? How can I control the width of the stalk? I want to get to something like this, but I haven't found any hint on how to do it:[image]

Comment: `?arrow()` shows only built in shape options are opened or closed for arrow heads, you would change stem width with `geom_segment(size = ...,)`

Comment: The documentation for `arrow` in the the grid package.